# Change countdown timer on location (or button to click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I am using this https://github.com/sonnyt/downCount for my countdown and here is the script

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('.countdown').downCount({
  date: '12/25/2015 00:00:00',
 
 });
});
</script>
```

I am launching the website tonight and I need the countdown to change for U.S visitors. Is there any way I can change the setting to U.S Location from U.K?

There is a offset: -5 setting but I don't know how to change it for locations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  
  var strDateTime = "12/25/2015 00:00:00  GMT -7";
  var myDate = new Date(strDateTime);
  var LocalDate = myDate.toUTCString();
  alert(LocalDate);
 $('.countdown').downCount({
  date: LocalDate,
 
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hello you can convert your time based on the following code

If the user run the page FROM us then it will show US start time and if he run from UK then user can see UK local time.

Comment: Thanks! How do I add this into the code I added in the question? Or does this go in a different file?

Comment: Nope let me create snippet for you

Comment: Thanks very much! Could you please check the time for me on the counter and let me know what your location is please? http://xmascount.com/

Comment: It Show  me 77Days 17 Hr. 22 min

Comment: What country are you from? Thank you

Comment: ok is this accurate? - Mine says 77 days 13 hrs 7 mins. Thought india is +05:30 ?

Comment: It's 2 hours more than it should be . hmmm check http://www.yourchristmascountdown.com/

Comment: I have change Function can you please check the snippet

Comment: a pop-up appears which tells me when it's Christmas. I don't need that to pop up but the time is still 2 hours too much

Comment: Can you please tell me the GMT timezone for which you want to show?

Comment: GMT it still doesn't change it for some reason with -7

Comment: it's changing minutes on the counter, not hours